# Replacement for OkNegotiatedContentResult in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**I have following code:**

```
    public IActionResult PostOpenBase64([FromBody]Open64Request request)
    {
        string param = Base64.DecodeFromBase64(request.b64);
        EvaluationParameter ep = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EvaluationParameter>(param);
        OpenRequest or = new OpenRequest();
        FindRequest fr = new FindRequest();
        or.Parameters = ep;
        fr.Parameters = ep;
        IActionResult ret = Post(fr);

        var contentResult = ret as OkNegotiatedContentResult<FindResponse>;

        FindResponse response = contentResult.Content;

        if (response.MustOpen || response.EvaluationId == 0)
        {
            Post(or); //Open
            ret = Post(fr);
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

The problem here is **OkNegotiatedContentResult** is unknown is ASP.Net Core.
Anyone have idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkResult`

Comment: What it is that you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there is another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Maybe! In Asp.Net MVC OkNegotiatedContentResult it works.

Comment: Try this: `FindResponse findResponse = new FindResponse();`  `var contentResult = ret as OkObjectResult(findResponse);`

Comment: I'll try to do that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I managed to solve according below in ASP.Net Core:**

```
 public IActionResult PostOpenBase64([FromBody]Open64Request request)
    {
        string param = Base64.DecodeFromBase64(request.b64);
        EvaluationParameter ep = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EvaluationParameter>(param);
        OpenRequest or = new OpenRequest();
        FindRequest fr = new FindRequest();
        or.Parameters = ep;
        fr.Parameters = ep;
        IActionResult ret = Post(fr);

        var contentResult = ret as OkObjectResult;
        FindResponse response = (FindResponse)contentResult.Value;

        if (response.MustOpen || response.EvaluationId == 0)
        {
            Post(or); //Open
            ret = Post(fr); //Find
        }

        return ret;
    }
```